# How to add a cooldown/rate-limit to a stream in Kafka Streams?

Tags: scala, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to streaming data processing, and have what I feel like must be a very basic use case.

Let's say I have a stream of `(User, Alert)` tuples. What I want is to rate-limit that stream per user. I.e. I want a stream that only outputs an alert for a user once. In the following lets say 60 minutes, any incoming alert for the user should just get swallowed. After those 60 minutes, an incoming alert should trigger again.

**What I tried:**

Using `aggregate` as a stateful transformation but having the aggregate state be time-dependent. However, even though the resulting `KTable` has no change in the aggregate value, The KTable (as a changelog) will continue to send elements down, thus not achieving the desired effect of "rate-limiting" the stream

```
val fooStream: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream("foobar2")
fooStream
  .groupBy((key, string) => string)
  .aggregate(() => "constant",
    (aggKey: String, value: String, aggregate: String) => aggregate,
    stringSerde,
    "name")
  .print
```

That delivers the following output:

```
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000004]: string , (constant<-null)
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000004]: string , (constant<-null)
```

It's generally unclear to me how/when `aggregate` decides to publish elements downstream. My original understanding was that it was immediate, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Windowing shouldn't help here as far as I can see.

Is it possibly the case that the Kafka Streams DSL currently does not account for this use case of stateful transformation, similar to Spark's [updateStateByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#updatestatebykey-operation) or Akka's [statefulMapConcat](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#statefulMapConcat)? Will I have to use the lower-level Processor/Transformer API?

EDIT:

The [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537084) does go into the question of how record caching is causing some confusion as to when aggregations decide to publish elements downstream. However, the primary question was around how to achieve "rate-limiting" in the DSL. As @miguno points out, one would have to revert to the lower-level Processor API. Below I pasted the approach which is quite verbose:

```
  val logConfig = new util.HashMap[String, String]();
  // override min.insync.replicas
  logConfig.put("min.insyc.replicas", "1")

  case class StateRecord(alert: Alert, time: Long)

  val countStore = Stores.create("Limiter")
    .withKeys(integerSerde)
    .withValues(new JsonSerde[StateRecord])
    .persistent()
    .enableLogging(logConfig)
    .build();
  builder.addStateStore(countStore)

  class RateLimiter extends Transformer[Integer, Alert, KeyValue[Integer, Alert]] {
    var context: ProcessorContext = null;
    var store: KeyValueStore[Integer, StateRecord] = null;

    override def init(context: ProcessorContext) = {
      this.context = context
      this.store = context.getStateStore("Limiter").asInstanceOf[KeyValueStore[Integer, StateRecord]]
    }

    override def transform(key: Integer, value: Alert) = {
      val current = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val newRecord = StateRecord(value._1, value._2, current)
      store.get(key) match {
        case StateRecord(_, time) if time + 15.seconds.toMillis < current => {
          store.put(key, newRecord)
          (key, value)
        }
        case StateRecord(_, _) => null
        case null => {
          store.put(key, newRecord)
          (key, value)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't I see any output from the Kafka Streams reduce method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537084/why-dont-i-see-any-output-from-the-kafka-streams-reduce-method)

Comment: Not possible in DSL at the moment. Using PAPI would work.

Comment: PAPI = The Processor API in Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have a stream of `(User, Alert)` tuples. What I want is to rate-limit that stream per user. I.e. I want a stream that only outputs an alert for a user once. In the following lets say 60 minutes, any incoming alert for the user should just get swallowed. After those 60 minutes, an incoming alert should trigger again.

This is currently not possible when using the DSL of Kafka Streams.  Instead, you can (and would need to) manually implement such behavior using the lower-level Processor API.

FYI: We have been having discussions in the Kafka community around whether or not to add such functionality (often called e.g. "triggers") to the DSL.  So far, the decision has been to not at such functionality for the time being.

> It's generally unclear to me how/when `aggregate` decides to publish elements downstream. My original understanding was that it was immediate, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Yes, that was the initial behavior for Kafka 0.10.0.0.  Since then (not sure what version you are using) we introduced record caching; if you disable record caching you get back the initial behavior, though from what I understand record caching would give you some kind of (indirect) knob for rate-limiting.  So must probably you'd want to keep the caching enabled.

Unfortunately the Apache Kafka docs don't yet cover record caching, for the meantime you may want to read http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#memory-management instead.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and timely comment. I suspected that this isn't currently possible in the DSL. Do you have a link to the discussions the community had around this topic? While the Processor API is nice enough, it certainly seems like a common use case that can be abstracted (like other frameworks do).

I updated the question with my workaround

Comment: Discussions: I don't remember off the top of my head.  Most probably in a discussion in the kafka-dev mailing list.